# enumitem: Understanding the usage of asterisk and exclamation mark in setting the different lengths

Tags: enumitem

In [enumitem manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), I can't find a clear explanation of the difference between the usage of exclamation mark and asterisk for `leftmargin`, `itemindent`, `labelsep`, `labelwidth`, and `labelindent`.

For example, what is the difference between setting `labelsep=*`

[image]

and `labelsep=!`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries#1.\space}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),labelsep=!]
 \litem{Term one} First term description.
 \litem{Term two} Second term description.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what was left unclear by the explanation on page 7 of the manual? I found it rather comprehensive.

Comment: @schtandard If it's very clear to you, post an answer that doesn't quote the text of the documentation, but instead explains it in another way (perhaps with some examples.)  This would be a really useful answer, I suspect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As explained in the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) documentation, the horizontal spacing in lists is composed of the parameters `leftmargin`, `itemindent`, `labelsep`, `labelwidth` and `labelindent` as follows:

[image: indentation in lists]

That is to say:

1. The values obey the relation

   ```
   leftmargin = labelindent + labelwidth + labelsep - itemindent
   ```
2. The right edge of the `\item` label will be indented by `labelindent + labelwidth`.
3. The first line of the Text of the `\item` will be indented by `leftmargin + itemindent`.
4. Subsequent lines will be indented by `leftmargin`.

As you can see, there are five parameters but they are not all independent. Given any four of them you can calculate the fifth, which is where the `!` and `*` values to these options come in.

---

Why have this redundancy at all? Well, in standard LaTeX, the parameter `labelindent` does not exist; it is introduced by `enumitem`. The author of the package felt that it might be useful to be able to directly set the indentation of the list label instead of having to calculate the other values manually in order to achieve the desired indentation.

By default, the new parameter `labelindent` is always calculated from the others. If you want to directly set `labelindent`, you will have to tell `enumitem` which parameter it should calculate instead. That is what the `!` value is for.

`*` does exactly the same thing, but it also first sets `labelwidth`. This is useful because the *right* edge of the label is indented by `labelindent + labelwidth`, so the left edge of the label will only be indented by exactly `labelindent` if the width of the label actually is `labelwidth`. `enumitem` tries to guess the width of the widest possible label by measuring the width of the label with value

- *0* if `label` is set using `\arabic*`,
- *viii* if `label` is set using `\roman*`,
- *m* if `label` is set using `\alph*` and
- similarly for the uppercase versions.

So, if you set `label=(\alph*)`, `enumitem` will measure the width of *(m)* and set `labelwidth` to this value. You can change this behavior using the `widest` option.

Note that this means that `labelwidth=!` and `labelwidth=*` do exactly the same thing.

---

Okay, so let's have a look at an example. `enumitem` acknowledges that the behavior of these values may be confusing and provides `\DrawEnumitemLabel` to visualize the current values, which I will use below. It

> [...] draws 4 rules from top to bottom, `labelindent`, `labelwidth`, `labelsep`, `itemindent` (thin if positive, thick if negative); the `leftmargin` is marked with two vertical rules.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\parindent=0pt
\newcommand*\printvalue[1]{\texttt{\string #1} : \the #1}

\begin{document}

% set some defaults:
\setlist{
        label=(\alph*),
        leftmargin=50pt,
        itemindent=10pt,
        labelsep=5pt,
        labelwidth=25pt,
        labelindent=10pt,
    }

By default, my definition of \verb|labelindent| is just ignored and it is calculated from the other values:
\begin{enumerate}
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item \printvalue\leftmargin
    \item \printvalue\itemindent
    \item \printvalue\labelsep
    \item \printvalue\labelwidth
    \item \printvalue\labelindent
\end{enumerate}

I can change that using the \verb|!| value.
For example, I can instead calculate \verb|labelsep| from the other values:
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=10pt, labelsep=!]
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item \printvalue\leftmargin
    \item \printvalue\itemindent
    \item \printvalue\labelsep
    \item \printvalue\labelwidth
    \item \printvalue\labelindent
\end{enumerate}

The \verb|*| value does exactly the same, only it also set the value of \verb|labelwidth| first.
It tries to guess the widest possible label (\textsl{0} for \verb|\arabic*|, \textsl{viii} for \verb|\roman*|, \textsl{m} for \verb|\alph*|):
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=10pt, labelsep=*]
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item \printvalue\leftmargin
    \item \printvalue\itemindent
    \item \printvalue\labelsep
    \item \printvalue\labelwidth
    \item \printvalue\labelindent
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Comment: This encyclopedic and informative answer is what I am looking for. Many thanks for your great explanation.

Comment: Thanks! This is amost exact answer I want! Here I have some small questions:  if I use `*` in `labelsep`, then `enumitem` will ignore what I set in `labelwidth` and just use the guessed widest width, and if I set `!`, `enumitem` will use the length I set in `labelwidth`?

Comment: In v3.7, the command `\DrawEnumitemLabel`'s performance changes, now it can show all 5 lengths, and changes thin and thick's situation. Maybe you can update the figure to make it more clear :)

Comment: Also, if I don't set `labelwidth`, it will give out a length of `20.00003pt`, maybe it is the default value of `labelwidth`?

Comment: @Syvshc Thanks for the note on the changed `\DrawEnumitemLabel`. Regarding your question: Yes, exactly. The default values for list layouts will depend on your document class (and font settings).